# How to properly use LiveData Transformation?

Tags: android-livedata, android-jetpack

I have a MutableLiveData

```
    val myMutableDataList = MutableLiveData<List<LiveData<Task>>>().apply {
    value = emptyList()
}
```

I have an ArrayList which contains LiveData

```
 var list:ArrayList<LiveData<Task>>
```

whenever an item of my `list` is changed I want to send that list to`myMutableDataList` and notifi that it was changed.

Currently I use this

```
`        list.forEach {
        it.observeForever {
            myMutableDataList.postValue(list)
        }
    }`
```

Transformation gives me an error

Comment: Do not store `LiveData` inside of another `LiveData`.

Comment: why should not I?